# Cannot sort date of birth using datetime with moment plugin in angular 2 projects

Tags: angular, datatables, momentjs

I have a table that displays id, name, and date of birth as below:

```html
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>date of birth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.dob }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I have the following codes to display the data table:

```js
declare const $;
export class Sampleomponent implements OnInit {

items: any[] = [
{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'sample1', "dob": '1900-01-01T05:00:00'  },
{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'sample2', "dob": '1937-10-11T05:00:00'  },
{ 'id': 3, 'name': 'sample3', "dob": '1954-02-01T05:00:00'  },
{ 'id': 4, 'name': 'sample4', "dob": '1940-12-01T05:00:00'  },
{ 'id': 5, 'name': 'sample5', "dob": '1910-01-01T05:00:00'  },
{ 'id': 6, 'name': 'sample6', "dob": '1901-10-09T05:00:00'  },
];

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadStyles();
    }, 300);
  }

loadStyles() {
$(function () {
  $.fn.dataTable.moment('dd/MM/yyyy');

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    title: 'test',
    buttons: [
        'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });
});
}

}
```

This table is able to display the table and sort all the columns except the dob column. I've followed by their [documentation](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment) but it gave me the same result. The date of birth or any other date field is not successfully sorted. Please assume that the `dob` is coming from the server as `datetime` format and I have all the necessary js codes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the dob field display correctly in the table, as `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taken this a little bit the wrong direction:

1. In DataTables, you only need to take special care of dates if they are not parseable, i.e if `Date.parse()` return `NaN` you'll need a plugin / formatter.
2. DataTables momentjs sorting plugin is such a formatter. It is used to convert data into the right parseable format, not to show or display data.
3. Your dates are perfectly fine, moment.js not needed. The native sorting breaks if *any* of the dates are illegal, for example `null`. To overcome this, you can force the `type` by

```js
    columns: [
      { data: 'dob', type: 'date' }
    ]
```

4. I believe you actually want to *show* the dates formatted as `DD/MM/YYYY` (`dd/MM/yyyy` return something like `Mo/01/yyyy`); you can use a `render` callback to show formatted dates while maintaining the native datetime sorting :

```js
    columns: [
      { data: 'dob', 
        type: 'date',
        render: function(data, type) {
          return type == 'display' ? moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : data
        }
      } 
    ]
```